# Editable uitextView with link data detector in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextview

When I make uitextView editable, links are not detected.

when I turn uitextView un-editable, links are detected.

How do I do both? Is it possible from IB?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have in my opinion interesting for you article (in ObjC) [article](http://www.ama-dev.com/editable-uitextview-with-link-detection/)